# JQuery .nextUntil() selecting heading into li

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, nextuntil

I'm trying to select all h3 tags under h2 tags even if into li whether ul or ol in a page, using .nextUntil().

HTML markup is like:

```
<h2></h2>
  <h3></h3>
  <h3></h3>
  <h3></h3>
<h2></h2>
  <h3></h3>
  <h3></h3>
  <h3></h3>
<h2></h2>
  <ol>
    <li>
     <h3></h3>
    </li>
    <li>
     <h3></h3>
    </li>
    <li>
     <h3></h3>
    </li>
  </ol>
```

Js is like:

```
var h2s = $('h2').toArray();

var h3s = [];

for (i = 0, i < h2s.length, i++){

  h3s.push($('h2').eq(i).nextUntil('h2', 'h3, li h3').toArray());

};

console.log(h3s);
```

The expected output is:

```
h3s[

 0: (3) [h3, h3, h3]
 1: (3) [h3, h3, h3]
 2: (3) [h3, h3, h3]

]
```

While the real output is:

```
h3s[

 0: (3) [h3, h3, h3]
 1: (3) [h3, h3, h3]
 2: []

]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after many experiments, thanks to [Bilel's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4929742/bilel) `each()` & `if(){}`.

here's a full sample https://playcode.io/533251 with a console.

To get all the h3 tags below each h2 tag even if they are into `<ol>` or `<ul>`

```
var h3s = [];

var i = 0;

$('h2').each(function(){

  if ($('h2').eq(i).nextUntil('h2').find('h3').length > 0) {

     h3s.push($('h2').nextUntil('h2').find('h3').toArray());

  } else {

     h3s.push($('h2').eq(i).nextUntil('h2', 'h3').toArray());

  } i++;

});
```

Or we can put the `if(){}` statement into simple `for(){}` loop depending on the length of an array of all h2 tags in the page

```
var h2s = $('h2').toArray();

var h3s = [];

for (i = 0; i < h2s.length; i++) {

  if ($('h2').eq(i).nextUntil('h2').find('h3').length > 0) {

     h3s.push($('h2').nextUntil('h2').find('h3').toArray());

  } else {

     h3s.push($('h2').eq(i).nextUntil('h2', 'h3').toArray());

  }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATED to fit to different code patterns]

---

jQuery [.nextUntil()](https://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/) expects a delimiter (like the `<h2>` here in your example). So the last part of the HTML code where `<h3>` elements are nested wouldn't be taken care of.
First, because there isn't a `<h2>` at the end. And second because they aren't siblings.

Using your code, I just added a conditional push where I check first if `<h3>` is the next element.

```js
var h3s = [];
i=0;
$( "h2" ).each( function( index, element ){
  if($(this).next('h3').length>0){
    if($(this).is('h2:last-of-type')){
h3s.push($('h2').eq(i).nextUntil('section').toArray());

} else {
  h3s.push($('h2').eq(i).nextUntil('h2').toArray());
  } }  else{
  h3s.push($('h2').eq(i).nextUntil('h2').find('h3').toArray());
  }
  i++;
});

console.log(h3s);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2></h2>
  <h3></h3>
  <h3></h3>
  <h3></h3>
<h2></h2>
  <ol>
    <li>
     <h3></h3>
    </li>
    <li>
     <h3></h3>
    </li>
    <li>
    
    </li>
  </ol>
<h2></h2>  
  <h3></h3>
  <h3></h3>
  <h3></h3>
<section>
```

PS: Notice that I removed the last `<h3>` for demo puropose here, so you could identify the last part!

Comment: first thanks for help <3

I don't think that jQuery .nextUntil() expects a delimiter or the `h3` tags that are nested below the last `h2` wouldn't be taken care of.

If you moved the `ol` to be under the second `h2` instead of the last one, It'll not get all the `h3` from inside the `ol`, while it'll get the `h3` that not inside `ol` after the last `h2` without delimiter tag.

Comment: Yes indeed it expects a delimiter... otherwise it would include unexpected following nodes  in your array :) I just updated my answer to fit to different code patterns. But still my first comment is valid and I just added what's missing in another condition. The code already handles any similar patterns... it's up to you to handle anomalies :)

Comment: Thanks very much, that's very good progress it worked only for h3s that are into the `<li>` [https://prnt.sc/rpple0](https://prnt.sc/rpple0), but the h3 that are **not** into `<li>` not detected, please note that I'm using jquery 3.4.1 [https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js).

Comment: Please, find a detailed sample in here with console log [https://playcode.io/533251](https://playcode.io/533251)